# Google App Engine does not support Runtime.addShutdownHook

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Regarding: Google Cloud Natural Language API Client

Will it work in Google App Engine (GAE)? I get exception 
"Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Google App Engine does not support Runtime.addShutdownHook".

My question is specific to the following client.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-language</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, google app engine doesn't not support it

Comment: Thank you very much. The document is not telling about that. Very bad. By the way, I have tested it using GCE it works. Thanks

Comment: If you tell us what you're trying to reach by doing this, we can probably suggest some workaround